# Swift: Converting SVG to UIBezierPath - image size too large

Tags: svg, swiftui, uibezierpath

I'm trying to animate an image I have which is essentially a line drawing. I have zero experience with UIBezierPath but I found a tutorial which shows how to convert an SVG to a UIBezier path. This is the effect I have achieved:

[image]

Now the animation itself is exactly what I want, however the frame in which the path is being drawn is too high and has a lot of white space (which the original SVG did not have).

The process I have followed is:

I ran the SVG file through [this converter](https://swiftvg.mike-engel.com) to produce a UIBezierPath. Then, I added the following extension to my Swift project:

```
extension UIBezierPath {
    public static func calculateBounds(paths: [UIBezierPath]) -> CGRect {
        let myPaths = UIBezierPath()
        for path in paths {
            myPaths.append(path)
        }
        return (myPaths.bounds)
    }
}
```

I added 2 separate paths with the following format:

```
public static var ctLogo1: UIBezierPath {
        let shape = UIBezierPath()
        shape.move(to: CGPoint(x: 304.28, y: 87.11))
        shape.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 304.17, y: 93.94), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 304.22, y: 87.17), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 304.17, y: 90.25))
        shape.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 304.17, y: 100.67))
        shape.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 300.83, y: 100.67))
...
return shape
}
```

Here is ShapeView:

```
struct ShapeView: Shape {
    let bezier: UIBezierPath
    let pathBounds: CGRect
    
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        let pointScale = (rect.width >= rect.height) ?
        max(pathBounds.height, pathBounds.width) :
        min(pathBounds.height, pathBounds.width)
        
        let pointTransform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1/pointScale, y: 1/pointScale)
        let path = Path(bezier.cgPath).applying(pointTransform)
        let multiplier = min(rect.width, rect.height)
        let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: multiplier, y: multiplier)
        return path.applying(transform)
    }
}
```

In ContentView.swift:

```
@State var endAmount: CGFloat = 0
    let pathBounds = UIBezierPath.calculateBounds(paths: [.ctLogo1, .ctLogo2])
```

And then this ZStack:

```
ZStack {
        ShapeView(bezier: UIBezierPath.ctLogo1, pathBounds: pathBounds)
                    .trim(from: 0, to: endAmount)
                    .stroke(Color(UIColor.i6.orange), lineWidth: 1.5)
                
        ShapeView(bezier: UIBezierPath.ctLogo2, pathBounds: pathBounds)
                    .trim(from: 0, to: endAmount)
                    .stroke(Color(UIColor.i6.darkGreyWithDarkMode), lineWidth: 1.5)
}
```

What I want is to be able to set the height of the ZStack and have the image to fit accordingly. However, when I set height and width of ZStack as follows:

```
.frame(width: .infinity, height: 200)
```

I get the following:

[image]

As you can see the image is much shorter than the height of the ZStack and maintains a lot of white space at the bottom. How can I get rid of this space so that the image can fill a greater portion of the ZStack?

Here's the [link to full svg file](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1bMqXHTNEYjP47FP3vLFnBCqdu8UZBSt7xC0d6wIMbw8/edit?usp=sharing), and the [conversion to bezier path](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1NT1-Po8__2wZfQuMb4Q1f0ZcUHff7ed8o-0cFUM5L98/edit?usp=sharing).